# Android .Net webservice using ksoap2-android-2.6.2.jar, a String parameter becomes nul

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have a problem in my testing Android App trying to pass a string parameter and I am expecting to return the value of the parameter,Here is my WebService code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/root")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public String SayHello(String name)
        {
                return name;

        }
    }
}
```

This WebService is hosted on my Local PC IIS
and here is my Android soap call:

```
public class CallSoap {

    // Lever one
    public final String SOAP_SAY_HELLO = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/root/SayHello";

    // Lever two operation
    public final String SAY_HELLO_OPERATION = "SayHello";
    // Lever four Soap target namespace
    public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/root";

    // Lever four Soap address
    public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/Service1.asmx";

    // Call say hello Method
    public String getHello(String nameVal) {
        String resp = new String();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                SAY_HELLO_OPERATION);


        request.addProperty("name", "Test");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.dotNet = false;
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Log.d("HTTP  REQUEST", "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + httpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("HTTP  RESPONSE", "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + httpTransport.responseDump);
        Object response1 = new Object();

        try {
            httpTransport
                    .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_SAY_HELLO, envelop);
            if (envelop.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject = SUCCESS
                SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelop.bodyIn;
                response1 = envelop.getResponse();
            } else if (envelop.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) { // SoapFault =
                                                                // FAILURE
                SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelop.bodyIn;
                response1 = soapFault.getClass();
                throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
            }

            return resp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return resp;

    }

}
```

I am getting Empty value as returned value and if I check soap envelope i can see my parameter in a packet. i have no Ideas what is happening to the parameter was sent.

Please anyone who can help me to identify where am wrong, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I Find what was wrong; when I hosted the webservice to local IIS, I had  to add the security of the folder contain the hosted webservice file and in my code I had to change `envelope.dotNet=true` not `envelope.dotNet=false` that is all.